# Kubernetes pods scheduled to non-tainted node

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a GKE Kubernetes cluster and two workloads deployed on that cluster, There are separate node pools for each workload. The node pool for celery workload is tainted with 
`celery-node-pool=true`. 
The pod's spec has the following toleration:

```
tolerations:
- key: "celery-node-pool"
  operator: "Exists"
  effect: "NoSchedule"
```

Despite having the node taint and toleration some of the pods from celery workload are deployed to the non-tainted node. Why is this happening and am I doing something wrong? What other taints and tolerations should I add to keep the pods on specific nodes?

Answer (score 1):

**Using Taints:**

Taints allow a node to repel a set of pods.You have not specified the effect in the taint. It should be `node-pool=true:NoSchedule`. Also your other node need to repel this pod so you need to add a different taint to other nodes and not have that toleration in the pod.

**Using Node Selector:**

You can constrain a Pod to only be able to run on particular Node(s) , or to prefer to run on particular nodes.

You can label the node

```
kubectl label nodes kubernetes-foo-node-1.c.a-robinson.internal node-pool=true
```

Add node selector in the pod spec:

```
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    env: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  nodeSelector:
    node-pool: true
```

**Using Node Affinity**

`nodeSelector` provides a very simple way to constrain pods to nodes with particular labels. The affinity/anti-affinity feature, greatly expands the types of constraints you can express.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: with-node-affinity
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: node-pool
            operator: In
            values:
            - true
  containers:
  - name: with-node-affinity
    image: k8s.gcr.io/pause:2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

> What other taints and tolerations should I add to keep the pods on specific nodes?

You should also **add a `node selector` to pin your pods to tainted node**, else pod is free to go to a non-tainted node if scheduler wants.

```
kubectl taint node node01 hostname=node01:NoSchedule
```

If i taint node01 and want my pods be placed on it with `toleration` need `node selector` as well.

> nodeSelector provides a very simple way to constrain(affinity) pods to nodes with particular labels.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  tolerations:
  - key: "hostname"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "node01"
    effect: "NoSchedule"
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/hostname: node01
```